# Change the text color of system emails

Tags: magento2, email, less

How do I change the font color of system emails like "forgot password".

I currently have white font color and white background.

I need this to work in Outlook, Thunderbird an any webmailer.

I tried overriding `email.less`, `email-fonts.less`, `email-inline.less` in my custom theme with no success.

Comment: open mail in browser then using firebug find the class,id or any css selector then add style tag and property as per your requirement in email template file(phtml). its definitely reflect.  but I am not sure this is the right way to done this.

Comment: and what less file am I supposed to modify?

Comment: sorry dude. it is a trick only.still I am not working in email concept. my friend gets struggle like you that time I can give this suggestion after that he get success to change style of email.  I am not much help you.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer:

It's the `_email-base.less`

```
.main-content {
    background-color: @email-content__background-color;
    padding: @email-body__padding;
    color: #333333 !important;
}
```

Comment: Hello @Philipp Sander, Does this change color for all email templates ?

Comment: It will only change it for the parts that a in an element with the class "main-content"